# Capitalize doesn't work on special characters - Python

Tags: python, string, utf-8, character, capitalize

I've been trying to capitalize loads of strings, and some of them start with utf-8 characters.
Problem is, they don't capitalize!

```
mystring = 'lucas'
mystring.capitalize() # returns 'Lucas'

mytring = 'æthelred'
mystring.capitalize() # returns 'æthelred'
```

Same with vowels containing `´^¨ and the characters ð, þ, e.t.c.
What do I do to solve this?

I actually don't have access to the string, I get them somewhere else, in a text file...

Comment: `mystring.decode("utf-8").capitalize()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You omit `u` . the string needs to be defined as unicode for python !

```
>>> mytring = u"æthelred"
>>> print mytring.capitalize()
Æthelred
```

As in `python 3` strings are unicode by default you dont need `u` .

```
>>> "æthelred".capitalize()
'Æthelred'
```

Comment: this answer is correct for python 2.x.  In python 3.x, strings are unicode by default, so Leandro's code should work fine

Comment: @stochastic yes , thanks for reminding ! i'll update the answer

Comment: how do I define a string as unicode when it's already in a variable? Sorry, quite new to this.

Comment: @LeandroLyra just use `unicode` function : `>>> unicode('abc')
u'abc'`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python 2 this will also work.  At the top of your file put:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

This will force Python 3 like behavior for strings, making them unicode by default.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, there are several stuff it can't decode this way. I'm also declaring utf-8 at the beggining of the file, it shouldn't be a problem.